# Uncheck CheckBoxes with Javascript Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

First thing, I searched SO and there are many questions with same title but none of them has the answer and I tried all of these answers with many different versions of my own but nothing works.

So, I have a form with many checkboxes and I want to uncheck all checkboxes when user change the user from **userSelection** list. like this

```
<form id="myForm">
    <select id="userSelection" onchange="userChange()">
        <option value="0" acl="">Select User</option>
        <option value="1" acl="2,5">ABC</option>
        <option value="2" acl="3,4">DEF</option>
    </select> 

    <label><input type="checkbox" ac="2" name="chkAc"><p>Income / Expense</p></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" ac="3" name="chkAc"><p>Donations</p></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" ac="4" name="chkAc"><p>Annual Fees</p></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" ac="5" name="chkAc"><p>Members Password</p></label>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkUncheckFields(isAllCheck)
  {
     var cbarray = document.getElementsByName('chkAc');
     for(var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++)
     {
          isAllCheck == false? cbarray[i].checked=false : cbarray[i].checked = true;
     }
  }

  function userChange()
  {
     checkUncheckFields(false);
     var access = $("#userSelection option:selected").attr('acl').split(',');
     $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function()
     {
        if(access.indexOf($(this).attr('ac')) > -1)
        {
            $(this).attr('checked',true);
        }
     });
  }
</script>
```

Now when I go to my page, manually check all of these checkboxes and then change my user from userSelection list, it does not uncheck checkboxes and if does uncheck all checkboxes then It doesnot check checkboxes meeting condition in user change. I am using JQuery 1.11.0

I have made JSBin here Please check it http://jsbin.com/famehaguni/1/watch  plese first check all checkboxes and then change user. Then you can see in our userChange() function we have given the condition to check checkboxes with user's acl attibute values but it doesnot check them means when you select ABC user then it should check 2 and 5 Checkboxes and if you choose DEF user then it should check 3 and 4 checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using this:
// to set unchcked all check boxes with `name=chkAc;`

```js
function checkUncheckFields()
  {
  $("[name=chkAc]").each(function(){
      $( this ).attr('checked', false);
    });
  
  }

  function userChange()
  {
  var access = $("#userSelection option:selected").attr('acl').split(',');
  checkUncheckFields();
  $("[name=chkAc]").each(function(){
  if($.inArray($(this).attr('ac'),access) >= 0)// your way of checking will also work.
        {
     
         $(this).prop('checked', true);
        }
  });
  
         
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" >
   <select id="userSelection" onchange="userChange()">
    <option value="0" acl="">Select User</option>
    <option value="1" acl="2,5">ABC</option>
    <option value="2" acl="3,4">DEF</option>
</select>
    <br/>
    <label><input type="checkbox" ac="2" name="chkAc"><p>Income / Expense</p></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" ac="3" name="chkAc"><p>Donations</p></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" ac="4" name="chkAc"><p>Annual Fees</p></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" ac="5" name="chkAc"><p>Members Password</p></label>
</form>
```

Comment: Suchit Please see my updated question, I have updated my userChange() function and added some code which does not work when uncheck works. It is important

Comment: I have made JSBin here Please check it http://jsbin.com/famehaguni/1/watch  plese first check all checkboxes and then change user. Then you can see in our userChange() function we have given the condition to check checkboxes with user's acl attibute values but it doesnot check them.

Comment: @NoOneSeesMe i have added the required code you can check it.

Comment: Thanks Suchit. It worked. Thanks Alot. After I got your answer I realized to search for difference between attr() and prop() and there is a very important difference. Thanks Alot

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removeAttribute, try:

Edit: based on your comment, try this:

```
function userChange()
{
  checkUncheckFields(false);
  var acc = $("#userSelection option:selected").attr('acl');
  var access = acc.split(",");
  for(var i=0; i < access.length; i++)
  {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function()
    {
      if(access[i] == $(this).attr('ac'))
         $(this).attr('checked',true);
    });
  }
}
```

It works.

Comment: Try, isAllCheck=== false? maybe?

Comment: I have made JSBin here http://jsbin.com/famehaguni/1/watch please check it. First Check all checkboxes and then change user. And you can see while in our userChange() function we have coded to check user acl attribute value still does not check it.

Comment: check my updated comment. You were parsing the attribute value incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer:

The HTML

```
<form id="myForm">
<select id="userSelection" >
    <option value="0" acl="">Select User</option>
    <option value="1" acl="2,5">ABC</option>
    <option value="2" acl="3,4">DEF</option>
</select> 

<label><input type="checkbox" ac="2" name="chkAc"><p>Income / Expense</p></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ac="3" name="chkAc"><p>Donations</p></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ac="4" name="chkAc"><p>Annual Fees</p></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ac="5" name="chkAc"><p>Members Password</p></label>
</form>
```

The Javascript

```
function checkUncheckFields(isAllCheck)
{
      if(isAllCheck)
              $("input[name='chkAc']").attr("checked", "checked");
         else
            $("input[name='chkAc']").removeAttr("checked");             
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#userSelection").change(function(){
        checkUncheckFields(false);
    })
})
```

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcravtdL/)

Answer (score 0):

You can see my [DEMO CODE](http://jsbin.com/soxilo/1/edit)

You should change function checkUncheckFields:

```
<form id="myForm" >
<select id="userSelection" onchange="userChange()">
    <option value="0" acl="">Select User</option>
    <option value="1" acl="2,5">ABC</option>
    <option value="2" acl="3,4">DEF</option>
</select> 
<br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" ac="2" name="chkAc"><p>Income / Expense</p></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ac="3" name="chkAc"><p>Donations</p></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ac="4" name="chkAc"><p>Annual Fees</p></label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ac="5" name="chkAc"><p>Members Password</p></label>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkUncheckFields(isAllCheck)
   {
     var cbarray = document.getElementsByName('chkAc');
     for(var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++)
     {
      if (!isAllCheck) {cbarray[i].checked = false; } else cbarray[i].checked = true;
     }
    }

  function userChange()
   {
     checkUncheckFields(false);
     var access = $("#userSelection option:selected").attr('acl').split(',');
     $('#myForm input[type=checkbox]').each(function()
       {
         if(access.indexOf($(this).attr('ac')) > -1)
          {
             $(this).attr('checked',true);
          }
      });
   }
  </script>
```

Comment: I tried this also. Ryan please see my updated question

Comment: Your demo is not working good. Please try your demo it doesn't let checkbox even checked

Comment: Ryan please see my updated question, I have updated my userChange() function and added some code which does not work when uncheck works

Comment: I don't find `#usersList` and `#acLevels` in your code. So i don't understand your request.

Comment: Sorry I forgot. Please see now

Comment: Ok. I have updated my code. You can see again. This code working